# Mapping url with view name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I am using tiles + Spring MVC.
When I have a view called `A`, I can access it directly without making any mapping with the url `/A`.
My problem is that I have some views called `A/B/C` but I cannot access them with `/A/B/C`.
I don't really want to make a controller just for that.
What are my options?

BTW: I am not sure of who is responsible for mapping the Url to the view name.Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`<mvc:resources>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).

And about mapping URL to view
1. Dispatcher servlet receives the request
2. It asks handler mapping to find out corresponding controller.
3. Then request is forwarded to corresponding controller.
4. Controller returns the model (i.e data) and logical view name.
5. View resolver helps dispatcher servlet to find out actual view from logical view name.

[image]
[**Source**](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where have you find this diagram? Very nice. Anyway, unfortunately I don't think that `mvc:resources` is what I am looking for. I already use it for the images, css etc... But, correct me if I am wrong, it doesn't work with views?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple controllers in your mvc namespace config declaratively with the view-controller element like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    ...
    <mvc:view-controller path="/A/B/C" view-name="A/B/C" />
    ...
</beans>
```

If you have lots of views that follow this pattern, you could think about implementing your own ViewResolver that maps whole paths to view names. Have a look at UrlBasedViewResolver for inspiration.